# Contrast testing for nested lm

Tags: r

I have a dataset with several grouping variables: CI (control/impact), BA (before/after), Time (years, either "1" or "2", nested in BA), and Month (factor, crossed with Time). I want to test specific contrasts after fitting the model (for example - is there a difference between control and impact in the Before, Year 1, Month = 7 period). I'm getting errors, and can't figure out what's going on.

a subset of my dataset (approximately 1/4 of original data):

```
df <- structure(list(CI = c("C", "C", "I", "C", "I", "I", "C", "C", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "C", "C", "I", "C", "C", 
"I", "C", "C", "I", "I", "I", "C", "C", "C"), BA = c("A", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"A", "A"), Time2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
Month = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
Response = c(113.88752014619, 304.207128003067, 241.7310642075, 
604.669028829096, 402.638407934937, 19.0787049433441, 224.594531044096, 
102.158889818213, 72.0887353433368, 284.654363758235, 288.369185046419, 
26.8008534995586, 178.586792242734, 16.2735094079759, 138.172423258193, 
255.441227294758, 203.702896110198, 307.715788152883, 25.1695768835496, 
80.6953963840745, 174.332452696881, 96.6109435701337, 318.393256208769, 
338.175334072426, 21.8925598523342, 504.867294274189, 245.80372078514, 
359.272337190666, 180.562152271052, 345.409069132269)), .Names = c("CI", 
"BA", "Time2", "Month", "Response"), row.names = c("122", "391", 
"51", "110", "163", "90", "201", "200", "169", "7", "78", "88", 
"810", "173", "85", "3", "41", "202", "172", "126", "351", "82", "361", 
"191", "89", "79", "46", "381", "203", "118"), class = "data.frame")
```

Model specification:

```
mod <- lm(log10(Response) ~ BA*CI + Month*(BA/Time2) + Month:CI:(BA/Time2), data = df)
```

I would normally set up the contrasts the following way. However, I'm getting an error.

```
library(contrast)
library(multcomp)

cc <- contrast(mod, 
     a = list(Month = c("7"), Time2 = c("1"), CI = c("C"), BA = c("B")), 
     b = list(Month = c("7"), Time2 = c("1"), CI = c("I"), BA = c("B"))) 
summary(glht(mod, linfct = cc$X))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found that it is necessary to run `library(multcomp)` in order to access `glht` function.

Comment: I'll edit the question accordingly, thank you. However, I get the error at the `contrast()` call prior to the `glht()` call, so the question stands.